# Use RDP and local session at the same time?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Running Windows 10, I would like to run an RDP session and a local session at the same time.  Is there any way to make this work?  Normally logging in with RDP sends the local display output to the login screen.  The reason for this strange setup is this:

I will have 4 DisplayPort monitors attached to the GPU doing full-screen video playback, and I want to use a fifth monitor for controlling the playback app.  The GPU has only 4 outputs.  A second GPU could be an option, but I also prefer the convenience of controlling the video playback remotely from a laptop.

I'm running Windows 10, but I could upgrade to 11 or server 2019 if necessary.

Comment: I'm afraid not. Starting with WindowsXP, Microsoft locked down concurrent RDP sessions for their workstation OSes. Windows servers allow two concurrent sessions, and  you can purchase terminal services CALs to increase that. Microsoft introduced this limit on purpose (it's purely artificial), so its not something that is likely get better in the future.  you may be able to use a different screen sharing protocol to allow an additional session (vnc is an option for instance) or perhaps look into alternate RDP servers for windows workstations, but I wouldn't know about any myself.

Answer (score 2):

search for "rdpwrap" (github), it installs itself as an additional layer onto microsoft's default rdp, it bypasses microsoft's enforced limit, allowing local and remote sessions simultaneously, including allowing same user concurrent sessions too.

after configuring successfully, one could even initiate a "remote session" into any same/local-computer's user accounts ("alternative user account sessions" as-well-as "concurrent same user account sessions"), being able to use both simultaneously without actually having to "switch user"

for the remote session (same-computer's login #2), use the universal localhost ip but as client #2 (127.0.0.2)

for a 2nd remote session (same-computer's login #3), use localhost ip as client #3 (127.0.0.3)

etc etc